# Apache, .htaccess - Not working locally

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, relative-path, absolute-path

I have a rewrite rule in my .htaccess.

```
RewriteRule ^(.+?)$ /user_home.php?domain=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Which redirects `mysite.com/mypage` to `mysite.com/user_home.php?domain=mypage`

This works fine on my shared host, but when working locally, my site is located in `www/mysite/` and instead of redirecting to `www/mysite/user_home.php?domain=mypage` it tries to redirect to `www/user_home.php?domain=mypage` which doesn't exist.

I get the following error in my Apache Logs

```
[error] [client ::1] script 'C:/wamp/www/user_home.php' not found or unable to stat
```

How can I alter my .htaccess to make it direct to the file in the current directory using a relative path instead of an absolute path..

Comment: `/mysite/user_home.php?domain=$1`...

Comment: that will solve the problem locally but i'd prefer to have a more generic solution that will also work on a live server without having to change it.

Comment: I highly doubt you're going to find a "catch all" solution for this because the directory structure changes between environments. Simply don't push the .htaccess files between local and production.

Comment: that's disapointing..

Comment: That's mostly because `.htaccess` files are meant to be implemented at the server level, and not the software level.

Comment: I recommend to include a `RewriteBase /mysite`, but you still need to change its path. The advantage is you're just going to change `RewriteBase` path in a one single part of the script when you want to deploy your product on server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to remove leading slash from the target URL in your rule like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ user_home.php?domain=$1 [L,QSA]
```

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` is also needed to prevent infinite looping.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
RewriteBase /mysite/
RewriteRule ^(.+?)$ /user_home.php?domain=$1 [L,QSA]
```

You just have to add a [RewriteBase](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteBase) with the path of the root folder of your website.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be to add checks if there is a file called like this and set a RewriteBase:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase mysite/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.+?)$ /user_home.php?domain=$1 [QSA,L]
```